# How to align all text boxes in one single row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How to align all text boxes in a single row? but in IE it's looking like working but in chrome, it's not working. is there any way it works in both browsers align properly all textboxes?

**IE 11 looks like this:**

[image]

**Chrome looks like this:**
[image]

**OR** also not aligned properly:
   [ | ]
    OR
   [ |]

**HTML**

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <form #myform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myform)" class="form-form-submit">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_dob" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Fname *</label>
          <input type="text" name="fname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_ssn" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Last Number *</label>
          <input type="text" name="Lname">
        </div>
        <span>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
            <div class="line">|</div>
            <div>OR</div>
            <div class="line">|</div>
          </div>
        </span>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="form_ssn" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Code *</label>
          <input type="text" name="Cname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 30px;">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="saving">
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code looks fine...how does it look like in Chrome? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Are you sure you want them on a single row? How do want it to look on a mobile phone and on a small tablet in portrait mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is just adding a few extra pixels of padding somewhere which is why you see this effect happen in Chrome and not IE.

If you were to reduce the width of your IE window you'd see the same effect there.

The main issue is that your design doesn't quite work for smaller screens; as soon as the "Code"-element doesn't fit on the same row as the other elements, it'll be pushed down - but the "OR"-element doesn't follow.

You probably want to avoid this from happening regardless of screen width:

```
Fname [   ]   Last Number [   ]    OR 

Code [   ]
```

You probably want this instead:

```
Fname [   ]   Last Number [   ]   

OR 

Code [   ]
```

or maybe this is good enough

```
Fname [   ]   Last Number [   ]   

OR  Code [   ]
```

To achieve that I would suggest adding a wrapper around both the "OR"-element and the "Code"-element so that they stick together; if one element is pushed down, then the other follows.

I rewrote your markup a bit, adding a wrapper around "OR" and "Code". (uses `display:flex` just to vertically align the child-elements)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
<div class="container">
    <form #myform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myform)" class="form-form-submit">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_dob" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Fname *</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_ssn" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Last Number *</label>
                <input type="text" name="Lname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: flex;">
                <div style="display: inline-block;" class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="line">|</div>
                    <div>OR</div>
                    <div class="line">|</div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <label for="form_ssn" class="control-label font-weight-bold">Code *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Cname">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" [disabled]="saving">
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

note: if you Run this snippet make sure to "open fullscreen".

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 text-nowrap">
            <div class="line">|</div>
            <div>OR</div>
            <div class="line">|</div>
            </div>
```

Add "text-nowrap" class for main div and check it.

Comment: That code is invalid. You cannot have a block element (`div`) inside an inline element (`span`).

Comment: Yes right. Remove <span> tag.
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 text-nowrap">
        <div class="line">|</div>
        <div>OR</div>
        <div class="line">|</div>
        </div>

Comment: if you see "OR" between the boxes not align properly.  how to adjust?